# Import-Csv Select -Skip

Tags: powershell, csv, skip, import-csv

I have multiple CSV files that need to be merged to one. In every single CSV file there is a header and in the second row some text that I don't need.

I noticed the `| Select -Skip 1` statement for the headers. Now I was wondering how I can skip the 3rd row?

I tried this, but this gives me an empty file

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $CSVFolder -Recurse -Filter "*.csv" | %{
  Import-Csv $_.FullName -Header header1, header3, header4 |
    Select -Skip 1 | Select -Skip 2
} | Export-Csv "C:\Export\result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select-Object` doesn't allow you to skip arbitrary rows in between other rows. If you want to remove a particular row from a text input file, you can do so with a counter, e.g. like this:

```
$cnt = 0
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
  Where-Object { ($cnt++) -ne 3 } |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

If the records in your input CSV don't have nested line breaks you could also use `Get-Content`/`Set-Content`, which is probably a little faster than `Import-Csv`/`Export-Csv` (due to less parsing overhead). Increase the line number you want to skip by one to account for the header line.

```
$cnt = 0
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
  Where-Object { ($cnt++) -ne 4 } |
  Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$i=0;
import-csv "C:\temp2\missing.csv" | %{$i++; if ($i -ne 3) {$_}} | export-csv  "C:\temp2\result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing si skipping the first the rows in all user cases, just use -skip 3.

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\UserRecord.csv'
# Results
<#
Name     Codes
------- ---------
John    AJFKC,EFUY
Ben    EFOID, EIUF
Alex    OIPORE, OUOIJE
#>


# Return all text after row the Header and row 3
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\UserRecord.csv') | 
Select -Skip 3

# Results
<#
Ben    EFOID, EIUF
Alex    OIPORE, OUOIJE
#>
```

See also:

> [Parsing Text with PowerShell (1/3)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/parsing-text-with-powershell-1-3)